# Columns names goes away when using lapply

Tags: r, list

I'm trying to keep the column name in a list of data frames when using `lapply` function.
I have a list of data frames. Let's say:

```
lst:
[[1]]                           [[2]]
A   ind                        C    ind     
1    0                         4     2
2    1                         8     0
```

I'm trying to get elements of the first columns of each dataframe ([[1]] and [[2]]) which has the index 0 in the second column of each data frame.

I'm using the code

```
aux <- lapply(lst, function(x) x[,1][x[,2]==0])
```

And it is working. The only problem is that I 'd like to keep the first column names. It means I'd like to get

```
aux:
[[1]]                           [[2]]
  A                               C        
  1                               8
```

but I'm getting

```
aux:
[[1]]                           [[2]]
  V1                              V1        
  1                               8
```

How can I keep the column names intact?

---

**data**

```
lst <- list(
  data.frame(A=1:2, ind = 0:1),
  data.frame(C=c(4,8), ind = c(2,0))
  )
```

Comment: When I fix the bracket mismatch by replacing the extra `)` with `]` as @jogo points out, I don't get the same output as what you've posted here. Please make sure the code you post here matches the code you're actually trying to debug so we're all on the same page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can just subset the first column

```
lapply(lst, function(x) x[x[,2] == 0, 1, drop = FALSE])
```

---

Or with `tidyverse`, this can made more compact

```
library(purrr)
map(lst, ~ .x[!.x[,2],1,  drop = FALSE])
```

Comment: for me it is working if I put x[,2] instead of x[[2]].

Comment: @Arnaldo. If you have a matrix, then you need `x[,2]`

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way that might be a bit more readable, using `subset`,

```
lapply(l1, function(i) subset(i, i[2] == 0)[1])
```

Comment: Or `lapply(lst, subset, ind == 0, select = 1)`

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper yeap, Thanks. I usually try to avoid the short versions in order to make them as readable as possible